# Diagonalization of Hamiltonian

Tags: mathematical-physics, condensed-matter, operators, hilbert-space

Typically, one way of understanding the physics of an interacting quantum system is by diagonalizing the Hamiltonian. In principle, can we always diagonalize a Hamiltonian, such that it is expressed in terms of non-interacting particle states? If so, is the diagonalization unique?

Comment: Perhaps relevant for finite dimensions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix

Answer (score 4):

In Mahan may-particle physics P15:

> (for bilinear Hamiltonian)It is only necessary to find the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian matrix. Usually the matrix is of infinite dimensionality. But one may often diagonalize it exactly for many problems. Computers allow very accurate solutions for any case of interest. **If all Hamiltonians had only bilinear operators, then many-body theory would only be an exercise in matrix diagonalization. Fortunately, it is more fun than that.**

So I think we can't make interacting Hamiltonian to bilinear form without any approximation. If we can, there would be no many-body problem.

Comment: There's mean field theory, but that only gets you so far.